SASS throws an error while compile mixin with dynamic variable
I am getting an error when I try to compile scss code.
This is mixin.
@mixin border-radius($type) {
  @if $type == 'small' {
      $radius: .5rem;
  }
  @else {
     $radius: 1rem;
  }
  border-radius: $radius;

}


Here I'm applying this mixin here.
.hom_d1 {
  @include border-radius('small');
}

I've been stuck in this error, I don't know how to resolve it.
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
27 │     border-radius: $radius;

Even through the $radius is defined, I got this.

The error makes sense. It's due that variable is not mixin scope. Just move the $radius to the mixin level.
@mixin border-radius($type) {
  $radius: 1rem; // Default value
  @if $type == 'small' {
      $radius: .5rem;
  }
  @else {
     $radius: 1rem;
  }
  border-radius: $radius;
}

